# TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, blueprintjs

I have these types in a library I use (blueprint.js)

```
export const Intent = {
    NONE: "none" as "none",
    PRIMARY: "primary" as "primary",
    SUCCESS: "success" as "success",
    WARNING: "warning" as "warning",
    DANGER: "danger" as "danger",
};
export type Intent = typeof Intent[keyof typeof Intent];
```

I have a component which accepts a prop and the prop should be one of these values.

```
My component:

export type EXPORT_BUTTON_INTENT = 'PRIMARY' | 'SUCCESS' | 'WARNING' | 'DANGER' | 'NONE';

interface Props {
  exportButtonColor?: EXPORT_BUTTON_INTENT;
}

<Component 
    className={
        props.exportButtonColor ? Classes[`INTENT_${props.exportButtonColor}`] : ''
    }
/>
```

I want to basically send in any of the above values as exportButtonColor here. When I do this, I get this error.

> TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of
>   type 'string' can't be used to index type 'typeof
>   import("C:/Users/this-user/Code/Forecast-Manager/node_modules/@blueprintjs/core/lib/esm/common/classes")'.
>     No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on
>   type 'typeof
>   import("C:/Users/this-user/Code/Forecast-Manager/node_modules/@blueprintjs/core/lib/esm/common/classes")'.

Please advice me to fix this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where should I use this?